SwiftUI BarkMark with x and y argument calling a function
I am trying to build a SwiftUI Chart, where the call to BarMark would have the x: and y: arguments calling a private function.
Chart {
    ForEach(array) { data in
        BarMark(x: x(data), y: y(data))
            .foregroundStyle(.blue.gradient)
  }
}

// array is [MyStruct], so data becomes an element of this array, being of type MyStruct
// MyStruct is a custom struct containing a date: Date, and a value: Double as properties

private func x<T: Plottable>(_ data: MyStruct) -> PlottableValue<T> where T == Date {
    .value("Date", data.date, unit: .day)
}

private func y<T: Plottable>(_ data: MyStruct) -> PlottableValue<T> where T == Double {
    .value("Steps", data.value)
}

I am not sure I understand generics very well. Both function x() and y() are compiling, but with a compiler warning:
Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'T' non-generic; this is an error in Swift 6
How can I get rid of this compiler warning?
Working, but with the Swift 6 compiler warning.

The error is becuase there isn’t anything generic the functions will always return double or date respectively. Just get rid of the T and use the true type.

When I do that, the function signature is this:
private func x(_ data: MyStruct) -> Date
and I am getting now a compiler error instead of a warning, at the call site, saying:
Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'PlottableValue'

Replace the T/X with the Date/Double. I don’t mean for you to get rid of plottable just T

This works, thanks: private func x(_ data: MyStruct) -> PlottableValue<Date>.
